# In TeamCity is it possible to navigate your projects source code?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

Does anyone know of a way to view entire source of a build via TeamCity - Jenkins has a nice feature whereby you can get to the workspace really easily. Hope this is possible out-of-the-box or via some other method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to directly get to the source through the Team City interface, but I do know that as you inspect problems, you can get a stack dump. It wouldn't surprise me if you can.

But, I use a different work flow instead, since the CI's working environment should only be a checkout from your source. Therefore if you have your revision information, you can view the source from your repository:

- **Use the `%build.vcs.number.1%` property in your "Build Number Format" field;** this will place the revision ID into the build's name. You can then view that source exactly in the repository.
- You can configure where the checkouts go, but either way you can navigate to "Team City's" working directory if you have access to that box.

  - **You can get the temporary WC directory through the `%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%` property** if you want to see the directory on disk where the checkouts etc. happened at.
  - see [this TeamCity article](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Checkout+Directory) for more information on changing it.
- You can turn on VCS Labeling under the VCS Settings, where a build is auto-labeled in your repository. That naming convention is also configurable.

  - see [this blog](http://www.laurentkempe.com/post/Build-and-Deployment-automation-VCS-Root-and-Labeling-in-TeamCity.aspx) for more information.

Hope that helps.